# NullReferenceException in razor page accessing local, non-null variable

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages, nullreferenceexception

I'm running into a really weird case in a cshtml Razor Page where regular code in `@{ ... }` blocks can access and use a variable just fine, but attempting to access the same variables but in a `@(...)` context throws `NullReferenceException`s.

To debug the issue, I moved the model property navigation and access to a local variable that is definitely non-null and then try to print that with a `@(..)` block, but the `NullReferenceException` persists.

```
@foreach (var sibling in Model.SiblingApplications)
{
    string studentName = sibling.Student.ToString() ?? "";

    <div class="sibling half line">
        <div class="question-block grow">
            <div class="label">Name</div>
            @* NullReferenceException on the next line! *@
            <div class="value">@studentName</div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Originally, the `NullReferenceException` came from writing`@(sibling.Student)` directly, even though I added assertions above it to throw if any of the variables used by the property access or the `ToString()` override where `null`. Then I refactored the code to what you see above, storing the variable in a non-null string (and doubly ensuring that's the case by appending `?? ""` out of paranoia).

Despite all that the `NullReferenceException` remains. I'm unable to observe the issue locally in either of Debug or Release modes but it happens without fail and gets logged in-prod. I attempted to downgrade from .NET 7 to .NET 6 and tried deploying a Debug build instead of Release, but neither of those helped.

The stack trace isn't helpful; it just points to the line that's annotated with `NullReferenceException` above:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ProjectName.Pages.Forms.Pages_Forms_RegistrationForm.ExecuteAsync() in X:\ProjectPath\Pages\Forms\RegistrationForm.cshtml:line 240
...
```

Importantly, no exception is thrown on the code that actually access the model properties and generates the non-null string - again, the exception happens accessing this now-local, definitely-not-null variable.

Comment: That error doesn't seem like it cant access it but it is not populated/initiated so it is NULL.

Comment: Your code will still throw if `sibling.Student` is null

Comment: Did you mean `string studentName = sibling.Student?.ToString() ?? "";`? If `sibling.Student` is null then `.ToString()` will throw instead of giving you a null for the `??` operator.

Comment: @HasaniH no, I didn't mean that. The code *doesn't* throw (on that line) so `sibling.Student` is obviously non-null. The `?? ""` is in case the `ToString()` override returns a null string for some reason.

Comment: @derpirscher yes, but the stack trace would tell me on what line the exception happened and I would know it was because `sibling.Student` was null - but that doesn't happen. (I actually added a guard to check if the value was null and throw an exception, *and* I log the value of `sibling.Student` to seq and the value *isn't* null).

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi is there anything else in the stack trace? Even if `studentName` is null `<div class="value">@studentName</div>` shouldn't throw, you should just get an empty `<div>` so there has to be more going on here.

Comment: I posted the answer. The debugger was breaking and the exception was happening on the annotated line but the property being referenced was actually one used a couple of lines later. It seems there's some ambiguity in how Razor maps to actual code that resulted in the line number being a red herring (not a Debug vs Release issue) when it was actually a different property altogether. Thanks for the support, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure this out without attaching a debugger, after which it immediately became clear. (Figuring out how to attach a debugger in-prod was a different matter.)

While the exception was indeed being thrown on the annotated line, in the debugger the variable that caused the `NullReferenceException` is shown though it *isn't* named in the actual exception message or stack trace that are logged.

It turns out that (due to the optimizations?) the compiler was dereferencing two different values in one go, `@sibling.Student` (used on the same line) and `@sibling.AnotherProperty` (used a few lines later in the same for loop, not shown in the abbreviated example posted above).

It was the second access that was actually causing the `NullReferenceException`, although the stack trace and the debugger (even attached in Debug mode) both threw/broke at the end of the first line.

I have wondered before if it is possible to get the logged exceptions and stack traces to actually include the same information that the debugger emits (namely, the property or variable that was being dereferenced when the `NullReferenceException` occurred instead of just the line number) - that would have saved me (and you!) a lot of grief.